# Connecting to AWS RDS Postgres Instance from my Django Project (Settings.py)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

**settings.py**

```
import os
import dj_database_url
...

DATABASES = { 'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': 5432
    }
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'),conn_max_age=600)
```

- I have a environment variable in my machine
  `postgres://<user>:<password>@<host>:5432/cust_manage`
- this is to connect to my aws rds postgresql
- then when I start the server it returns this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dieth"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dieth"
```

- **QUESTION:**
  `How to connect my app to my aws rds that uses environment variable? so that I don't have to pass my real host and password to my settings.py. Thanks guys.`

Answer (score 1):

> You can use [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), Put the environment variables in a file
> (.env) and use these in settings.py file.

> $ pip install django-environ

```
.env
    DEBUG=on
    SECRET_KEY='-----------------'
    DATABASE_URL=psql://<user>:<passowrd>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>
```

settings.py

```
    environ.Env.read_env()
    env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

    DATABASES = {
        'default': env.db(),    #  It create the required connections string.
        'TEST': {'NAME': 'test_my_db'},
    }
```